# Apache Camel - Mock REST endpoint returns NullPointerException

Tags: java, apache-camel

I would like to mock responses from a REST endpoint so that I can test my route. I am following the Camel in Action book and have adapted the REST testing example [implementation](https://github.com/camelinaction/camelinaction2/blob/master/chapter9/miranda/src/test/java/camelinaction/MirandaTest.java) as follows:

```
    @Override
    protected RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() throws Exception {
        return new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                from("jetty://http://localhost:9080/SERVICECALL")
                        .transform().message(m -> "endpoint")
                        .to("mock:endpoint");
            }
        };
    }


    @Test
    public void shouldCallRedaction() throws Exception {
        MockEndpoint mock = getMockEndpoint("mock:endpoint");
        mock.expectedBodiesReceived("endpoint");
        mock.whenAnyExchangeReceived(e -> e.getIn().setBody("endpoint"));

        String url = "http://localhost:9080/SERVICECALL";
        String response = template.requestBody(url, "test", String.class);
        assertEquals("endpoint", response);

        assertMockEndpointsSatisfied();

    }
```

The `getMockEndpoint` method returns a `NullPointerException`. When I run in debug I can see that the `CamelContext` is `null`, hence the exception. My intended behaviour is to instead receive plain text response "endpoint" when the endpoint `SERVICECALL` is called.

I'm confused as to why I am getting this exception (should I define the context for the mock somewhere?) and how I should correctly implement the mock endpoint to test the route.

Comment: What version of junit are you using? The error indicates that the `@Before` annotation of `CamelTestSupport` is not evaluated.

Comment: I'm using JUnit5

Comment: The camel in action example you are refering to uses junit4. Did you adapt your dependencies accordingly?

Comment: Yes I've tried both frameworks. My preference would be JUnit5 however.